# How should I interpret "it did not seem fantastic"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read a sentence in a story in my book which was:

> The little girl, (not so little anymore; the bumps her feet made under the covers, were half way down the bed, their big double bed that they let her be in for naps and when she was sick) had at last arranged herself, and from the way her fat face deep in the pillow shone in the sunlight sifting through the drawn shades, **it did not seem fantastic that some magic would occur, and she would take her nap like an infant of two.**

Should I interpret the highlighted part as meaning that "the occurring of the magic had become so common that it did not seem fantastic anymore" or does it mean that "as she has grown older, the imaginary magic wouldn't happen and thus the fantasy is not worth having"? Although I strongly believe that the former should be right, seeing the premises I started having second thoughts?

Comment: Kelvin, please **do not cross-post questions** between [ell.se] and this site. Please stop doing it.

Answer (score 1):

This is Fantastic in the earlier sense of *like fantasy* or *unbelievable*.

It did not seem *unbelievable* that some magic would occur.

Or It did not seem too *far fetched* that some magic would occur.

Comment: This is correct. More for the OP than the answerer, but it would be interesting to know where the quote is from and how old it is. [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=fantastic) says the more mundane use of "fantastic" for marvellous/wonderful/good dates back to 1938, while this feels like an older text based on things like sentence length and use of brackets.

Answer (score -2):

According to my opinion the text means that

it is not real that some magic would occur so that joanne would fall asleep fast like an infant

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/424695)